# Unit Test with Live Data always get error "Method getMainLooper in android.os.Looper not mocked."

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-livedata

In my ViewModel, I use live data to hold the response state. Here the code:

```
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: Repository): ViewModel() {

    private val _charData = MutableLiveData<Response<List<Character>>>()

    val charData: LiveData<Response<List<Character>>>
        get() = _charData

    init {
        getCharacters()
    }

    fun getCharacters(){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _charData.value = repository.getCharacters()
        }
    }
}
```

My test always fails with that error and the problem is in the line `_charData.value = repository.getCharacters()`. I also have looked at the same problem and it should be handled by adding `@get:Rule val instantExecutorRule: InstantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()`. However, the error still persists. Here my test code:

```
@RunWith(JUnit4::class)
class MainViewModelTest {
    @get:Rule
    val mainRule =  MainCoroutineRule()

    lateinit var repository: Repository

    lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

    @get:Rule
    val instantExecutorRule: InstantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @Before
    fun setUp(){
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this)
        repository = MockRepository()
        viewModel = MainViewModel(repository)
    }

    @Test
    fun getCharactersSuccess() = runTest {
        val observer = mock<Observer<Response<List<Character>>>>()
        viewModel.getCharacters()
        viewModel.charData.observeForever(observer)
        assertTrue(viewModel.charData.value is Response.Success)
    }
}
```

How should I fix this error?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

add

```
testOptions {
            unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
        }
```

Comment: Where? which nested level?

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution.
You can use Robolectric.
Replace `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)` with in your ViewModel Test class  `@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)`

Also use the below dependency for rorolectric

```
testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:4.11.1"
```